# Is it possible and/or ethically correct to add a bounty to a question I answer to?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I posted an answer to a question I view interesting, and that I often asks myself, namely [Should I add parameters to instance methods that use those instance fields as parameters?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166893/should-i-add-parameters-to-instance-methods-that-use-those-instance-fields-as-pa).

I would like to know... Is it advisable, ethical, and/or seen as a positive indicator to add a bounty to a question I posted an answer to ? I feel like there could be a better answer from +30K rep users such as Peter Torok for example...

Comment: Whose code of ethics do you wish to evaluate this action by?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's certainly possible.

The ethics should be irrelevant as there's no way that the bounty can be assigned to your answer. You can't assign it manually and there's no way it will be auto-assigned as your answer pre-dates the start of the bounty.

Comment: precise and fast answer as always. Thanks a lot Chris.

Comment: Imagine I could assign a bounty and win it.  Would it be unethical to award myself my own points?  Zero increase in net fake points that didn't matter anyways.

Comment: @WarrenP - you can't assign a bounty to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Some may see it as an attempt by you to promote your answer and get more votes, its not against the rules though, and if you make the bounty a larger one people would likely not complain about it.

Comment: ChrisF wrote that since my answer pre-dates the bounty it's not possible for the bounty to be assigned to me either manually or automatically.

Comment: no but it is possible if you put a 25/50 bounty on a question then a handful of up-votes leaves you with a gain in rep. this really only matters if you abuse low value bounties a lot.

Comment: ah I see what you mean, right.

Comment: If you've already answered a question the minimum bounty you can set is 100, exactly for the reason you're describing.